# windows phone display hijri date picker

Tags: calendar, datepicker, windows-phone, hijri

Can you please let me know how can I modify the silverlight toolkit date picker (toolkit:DatePicker) to work with hijri calendar 
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go the answer to your question which is tested on windows mobile 8

```
CultureInfo sa = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
sa.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new System.Globalization.HijriCalendar();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = sa;
// Sets the UI culture to Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = sa;
```